# Remove first occurence of an element using JavaScript or Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array like this -

```
["a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

I want to operate on this and filter it to remove only the first occurence of every element in the array.

The output in the above case is expected to be - `["a"]`

How can I achieve this using JavaScript or Lodash?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [Array - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 2):

By wanting the **first** one of duplicate following items, you could use [`Array#lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) along with a check of the actual index.

```js
const
    data = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
    result = data.filter((v, i, a) => i !== a.lastIndexOf(v));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an empty object as a map to easily check if the item has been found before and then use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove the ones you don't want.

```js
var list = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
var occurences = {};
var filteredList = list.filter(function(item) {
  if (item in occurences) return true; // if it has already been registered, add it to the new list
  occurences[item] = 1; // register the item
  return false; // ignore it on the new list
});
console.log(filteredList);
```

Shorthand version

```js
let list = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], occurences = {};
list = list.filter(item => item in occurences ? 1 : occurences[item] = 1 && 0);
console.log(list);
```

Answer (score -3):

you can simply use shift method checkout it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

Comment: This removes the first element, not the first occurrence of every element

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).